# How to set x_axis based on a list?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a histogram in which I need to fix x_axis as 1 to 10. I am a bit confused. Can I do that by using plt.hist function or do I need another approach?

```
from statistics import variance
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def HistPlot(N):
      Cards = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
      Deck = ([0])*10

      for i in range(0,N):
        X = np.random.randint(1, 11, (10))
        for r in range(0,len(X)):
          Deck[X[r]-1] = Deck[X[r]-1]+1
      v = round(variance(Deck),2)

      plt.plot(Cards, Deck,color='b')

      #plt.hist(Deck, bins=10)
      plt.xlabel('Cards')
      plt.ylabel('Freq.')

      s = "Histogram Plot with N = " + str(N) + ", Variance = " + str(v)

      plt.title(s)
      plt.show()


HistPlot(10)
HistPlot(100)
HistPlot(1000)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`plt.xlim(lower, upper)` is just the trick. If you add `plt.xlim(1, 10)` after `plt.plot(...)` it should work for you.

[image: example]

Comment: Thanks, also to make it histogram should only change plt.plot to plt.bar? Can I make it by using plt.hist?

Comment: Happy to help. Yes in your case you'd use `plt.bar(Cards, Deck)`. You can use `plt.hist` when your data is not already separated into classes, for example if `Deck` was a list of `N` outcomes, eg. all values in your card class range `[1..10]`.